# Fast Lookup Data Structure in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am very new to C#, here is the problem statement which I am trying to solve:

I have the collection of objects, and I want to perform fast lookup everytime user search for any particular object by name property.

More specific: Collection of 100 objects and searching should not take much time.

My understanding is Dictionary will be fastest for such lookup, is this correct?

Comment: Searching 100 objects shouldn't be a performance problem. But your question is too vague to get a good answer. Yes Dictionary or Hashset are fast on lookups

Comment: At a sample size of 100 objects I don't think there will be much performance to gain by using dictionaries, but that is probably still the most relevant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure

Comment: There's an important principle you need to understand about performance tuning: you don't actually need to waste your time hyper optimizing things if the performance isn't actually a problem in the first place. What's going so slow with 100 objects that you're having performance problems?

Comment: If you adequately abstract your business objects, you can later replace the underlying implementation (e.g. List to HashTable) with minimal trouble.

Comment: Read Eric Lippert's [Performance rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends, in most of special case, 100 object will be ok, there will be no time issue.

If your name is a really long string, if you are using lambda linq `object.Where(a=>a.name==search)`, it will use string matching and will take more time (string matching on a list is like O(n) * O(n)), so, yes, using dictionary will be much more faster (O(1)).